# Не осуществляется перевод строки с помощью ugettext_lazy в Django 2.2

Tags: python-3.x, django

Мне необходимо перевести строку на русский, пытаюсь это сделать с помощью `from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _`, на выходе строка как была на английском так и остается.
Пробовал в шаблоне выполнять перевод через тэг `{% load i18n %}` и последующий `{% translate "data" %}`, тогда возникает ошибка, что тег translate не загружен.

Мой код:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
...
   if self.last_online:
      return _('Last visit {}').format(naturaltime(self.last_online))
...
```

Настройки:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru-RU'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Moscow'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Во-первых, тега translate не существует в старой версии Django. Во-вторых, вы не забыли обновить ваш django.po файл и скомпилировать командой compilemessages?

Comment: Не обновлял, что нужно прописать для обновления?

Comment: Видимо, вам стоит начать с чтения документации https://djbook.ru/rel1.8/topics/i18n/translation.html#localization-how-to-create-language-files

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо)